# How to extract value from NSMutable array and put it in NSArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa

I have NSMutableArray like following:

In .h

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *arrReceipes;
```

In .m

```
@synthesize arrReceipe;
```

Inside a method

```
arrReceipes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];    
NSArray *arrReceipesTime1;    
NSArray *arrReciepHeart;     
NSArray *arrRecipeLifestyle;     

arrReceipesTime1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Half an hour or less",@"About an     hour",@"More than an hour", nil];     

NSDictionary *arrReceipeTime1Dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:arrReceipesTime1 forKey:@"Find Recipes"];    

arrReciepHeart = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"HealthyAndDelicius", nil];    
NSDictionary *arrRecipesHeartDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:arrReciepHeart   forKey:@"Find Recipes"];     

arrRecipeLifestyle = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Recipe for fall",@"Quick and   easy",@"Cooking for kids",@"Easy entertaining",@"American classics",@"Outdoor cooking",   nil];     
NSDictionary *arrRecipeLifestyleDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:arrRecipeLifestyle forKey:@"Find Recipes"];     

[arrReceipes addObject:arrReceipeTime1Dict];
[arrReceipes addObject:arrRecipesHeartDict];
[arrReceipes addObject:arrRecipeLifestyleDict];
```

That is "arrReceipes" is my NSMutable array.

Now I want to extract the value/string of "arrReceipes" and put it into "NSArray * somevariable".

How can I do this?

This I' doing for :

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"]) {
       NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView1 indexPathForSelectedRow];
       RecipeDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

       destViewController.recipeName = [arrReceipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

In my 3rd line above(in 'if') if I'm giving "arrReceipes" its throwing exception in "main" method.But, if, instade of giving "arrReceipes" I'll give "somevariable" its working fine.

Hope you understand my problem.Please help.Thanks.

Comment: What exception is it throwing, and on what line?

Answer (score 1):

The objects that you're putting into `arrReceipes` are dictionaries, so the `destViewController.recipeName` should be a dictionary if you want to pass it one of those objects.

Comment: Hi Phillip, Could you please more elaborate.Give some example code.Thanks.

Comment: What part of "`destViewController.recipeName` should be a dictionary" don't you understand?

Comment: Or, (probably more likely) he needs to extract the recipe name from the dictionary and set the variable in the new view controller.

Comment: Certainly **deciding** what data type is to be passed would be a good step.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write in an NSArray.

However you can do something like this:

```
NSArray * somevariable = [arrReceipes copy];
```

Also you can modify your code to write the data into a NSMutableArray and then copy it to `arrRecipes`

Comment: give full answer, he cant use copy (ARC will create issue)

Comment: Why would copy give problems in ARC. I've just copy just fine in a project with ARC.

Comment: I tryed doing:NSArray * somevariable = [arrReceipes copy]; But, this does not help.Its showing same exception.Any other solution??

Comment: @Jyotiranjan - I've checked the iOS documentation again, and I still can't find a "same" exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

`NSArray *somevariable = [NSArray arrayWithArray:arrReceipes];`

NSMutableArray is a subclass of an NSArray so you can just use NSArray methods